# I see a white space at the top of the page

Tags: wordpress, iframe, whitespace

hello everyone i have a problem. I'm building a site with wordpress. When you view the page in AVG browser the page doesn't show any white space, but if you view the page in google chrome I see white space in the top of the page. This is the link of my website (see it with google chrome):
https://sharedkitchen.site/landing-page/
if i inspect the page, i see that google chrome creates an iframe that i didn't add on my site.
if i inspect the page, this is a piece of code from my page:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: block; height: 444px;" data-ad-format="fluid" data-ad-layout-key="-6d+ce-16-8z+wv" data-ad-client="ca-pub-9730034314236830" data-ad-slot="9113356153" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" data-ad-status="unfilled"><div id="aswift_1_host" style="border: none; height: 444px; width: 584px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; visibility: visible; background-color: transparent; display: inline-block;" tabindex="0" title="Advertisement" aria-label="Advertisement"><iframe id="aswift_1" name="aswift_1" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;border:0;width:584px;height:444px;" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" width="584" height="444" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-9730034314236830&amp;output=html&amp;h=444&amp;slotname=9113356153&amp;adk=4050069083&amp;adf=1739614658&amp;pi=t.ma~as.9113356153&amp;w=584&amp;lmt=1677003232&amp;rafmt=11&amp;format=584x444&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fsharedkitchen.site%2Flanding-page%2F&amp;host=ca-host-pub-2644536267352236&amp;wgl=1&amp;uach=WyJXaW5kb3dzIiwiMTAuMC4wIiwieDg2IiwiIiwiMTEwLjAuNTQ4MS4xMDQiLFtdLGZhbHNlLG51bGwsIjY0IixbWyJDaHJvbWl1bSIsIjExMC4wLjU0ODEuMTA0Il0sWyJOb3QgQShCcmFuZCIsIjI0LjAuMC4wIl0sWyJHb29nbGUgQ2hyb21lIiwiMTEwLjAuNTQ4MS4xMDQiXV0sZmFsc2Vd&amp;dt=1677003229213&amp;bpp=17&amp;bdt=2212&amp;idt=3393&amp;shv=r20230215&amp;mjsv=m202302130101&amp;ptt=9&amp;saldr=aa&amp;abxe=1&amp;cookie=ID%3Dbdcaae410da2bb7a-22b28880eadc00e4%3AT%3D1676998403%3ART%3D1676998403%3AS%3DALNI_MYOVatVyObhJuGUHneGD_g80vL-2g&amp;gpic=UID%3D00000bba14bff1a4%3AT%3D1676998403%3ART%3D1676998403%3AS%3DALNI_MZ6YLgZlSFlG4bdwxbwyjREGhHvcA&amp;prev_fmts=0x0&amp;nras=1&amp;correlator=891157308941&amp;frm=20&amp;pv=1&amp;ga_vid=1061274858.1676998399&amp;ga_sid=1677003232&amp;ga_hid=1501342193&amp;ga_fc=1&amp;u_tz=60&amp;u_his=1&amp;u_h=768&amp;u_w=1366&amp;u_ah=728&amp;u_aw=1366&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_sd=1&amp;dmc=4&amp;adx=105&amp;ady=332&amp;biw=794&amp;bih=657&amp;scr_x=0&amp;scr_y=152&amp;eid=44759927%2C44773809%2C44759837%2C44759876%2C31072436&amp;oid=2&amp;pvsid=2310979411863847&amp;tmod=1207128482&amp;uas=0&amp;nvt=2&amp;fc=1920&amp;brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1366%2C0%2C1366%2C728%2C811%2C657&amp;vis=1&amp;rsz=%7Co%7CoeE%7C&amp;abl=NS&amp;pfx=0&amp;fu=128&amp;bc=31&amp;ifi=2&amp;uci=a!2&amp;fsb=1&amp;xpc=DDOUpZiKeH&amp;p=https%3A//sharedkitchen.site&amp;dtd=3454" data-google-container-id="a!2" data-load-complete="true"></iframe></div></ins>
   <div id="aswift_1_host" style="border: none; height: 444px; width: 584px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; visibility: visible; background-color: transparent; display: inline-block;" tabindex="0" title="Advertisement" aria-label="Advertisement"><iframe id="aswift_1" name="aswift_1" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;border:0;width:584px;height:444px;" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" width="584" height="444" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-9730034314236830&amp;output=html&amp;h=444&amp;slotname=9113356153&amp;adk=4050069083&amp;adf=1739614658&amp;pi=t.ma~as.9113356153&amp;w=584&amp;lmt=1677003232&amp;rafmt=11&amp;format=584x444&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fsharedkitchen.site%2Flanding-page%2F&amp;host=ca-host-pub-2644536267352236&amp;wgl=1&amp;uach=WyJXaW5kb3dzIiwiMTAuMC4wIiwieDg2IiwiIiwiMTEwLjAuNTQ4MS4xMDQiLFtdLGZhbHNlLG51bGwsIjY0IixbWyJDaHJvbWl1bSIsIjExMC4wLjU0ODEuMTA0Il0sWyJOb3QgQShCcmFuZCIsIjI0LjAuMC4wIl0sWyJHb29nbGUgQ2hyb21lIiwiMTEwLjAuNTQ4MS4xMDQiXV0sZmFsc2Vd&amp;dt=1677003229213&amp;bpp=17&amp;bdt=2212&amp;idt=3393&amp;shv=r20230215&amp;mjsv=m202302130101&amp;ptt=9&amp;saldr=aa&amp;abxe=1&amp;cookie=ID%3Dbdcaae410da2bb7a-22b28880eadc00e4%3AT%3D1676998403%3ART%3D1676998403%3AS%3DALNI_MYOVatVyObhJuGUHneGD_g80vL-2g&amp;gpic=UID%3D00000bba14bff1a4%3AT%3D1676998403%3ART%3D1676998403%3AS%3DALNI_MZ6YLgZlSFlG4bdwxbwyjREGhHvcA&amp;prev_fmts=0x0&amp;nras=1&amp;correlator=891157308941&amp;frm=20&amp;pv=1&amp;ga_vid=1061274858.1676998399&amp;ga_sid=1677003232&amp;ga_hid=1501342193&amp;ga_fc=1&amp;u_tz=60&amp;u_his=1&amp;u_h=768&amp;u_w=1366&amp;u_ah=728&amp;u_aw=1366&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_sd=1&amp;dmc=4&amp;adx=105&amp;ady=332&amp;biw=794&amp;bih=657&amp;scr_x=0&amp;scr_y=152&amp;eid=44759927%2C44773809%2C44759837%2C44759876%2C31072436&amp;oid=2&amp;pvsid=2310979411863847&amp;tmod=1207128482&amp;uas=0&amp;nvt=2&amp;fc=1920&amp;brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1366%2C0%2C1366%2C728%2C811%2C657&amp;vis=1&amp;rsz=%7Co%7CoeE%7C&amp;abl=NS&amp;pfx=0&amp;fu=128&amp;bc=31&amp;ifi=2&amp;uci=a!2&amp;fsb=1&amp;xpc=DDOUpZiKeH&amp;p=https%3A//sharedkitchen.site&amp;dtd=3454" data-google-container-id="a!2" data-load-complete="true"></iframe></div>
     <iframe id="aswift_1" name="aswift_1" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;border:0;width:584px;height:444px;" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" width="584" height="444" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-9730034314236830&amp;output=html&amp;h=444&amp;slotname=9113356153&amp;adk=4050069083&amp;adf=1739614658&amp;pi=t.ma~as.9113356153&amp;w=584&amp;lmt=1677003232&amp;rafmt=11&amp;format=584x444&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fsharedkitchen.site%2Flanding-page%2F&amp;host=ca-host-pub-2644536267352236&amp;wgl=1&amp;uach=WyJXaW5kb3dzIiwiMTAuMC4wIiwieDg2IiwiIiwiMTEwLjAuNTQ4MS4xMDQiLFtdLGZhbHNlLG51bGwsIjY0IixbWyJDaHJvbWl1bSIsIjExMC4wLjU0ODEuMTA0Il0sWyJOb3QgQShCcmFuZCIsIjI0LjAuMC4wIl0sWyJHb29nbGUgQ2hyb21lIiwiMTEwLjAuNTQ4MS4xMDQiXV0sZmFsc2Vd&amp;dt=1677003229213&amp;bpp=17&amp;bdt=2212&amp;idt=3393&amp;shv=r20230215&amp;mjsv=m202302130101&amp;ptt=9&amp;saldr=aa&amp;abxe=1&amp;cookie=ID%3Dbdcaae410da2bb7a-22b28880eadc00e4%3AT%3D1676998403%3ART%3D1676998403%3AS%3DALNI_MYOVatVyObhJuGUHneGD_g80vL-2g&amp;gpic=UID%3D00000bba14bff1a4%3AT%3D1676998403%3ART%3D1676998403%3AS%3DALNI_MZ6YLgZlSFlG4bdwxbwyjREGhHvcA&amp;prev_fmts=0x0&amp;nras=1&amp;correlator=891157308941&amp;frm=20&amp;pv=1&amp;ga_vid=1061274858.1676998399&amp;ga_sid=1677003232&amp;ga_hid=1501342193&amp;ga_fc=1&amp;u_tz=60&amp;u_his=1&amp;u_h=768&amp;u_w=1366&amp;u_ah=728&amp;u_aw=1366&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_sd=1&amp;dmc=4&amp;adx=105&amp;ady=332&amp;biw=794&amp;bih=657&amp;scr_x=0&amp;scr_y=152&amp;eid=44759927%2C44773809%2C44759837%2C44759876%2C31072436&amp;oid=2&amp;pvsid=2310979411863847&amp;tmod=1207128482&amp;uas=0&amp;nvt=2&amp;fc=1920&amp;brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1366%2C0%2C1366%2C728%2C811%2C657&amp;vis=1&amp;rsz=%7Co%7CoeE%7C&amp;abl=NS&amp;pfx=0&amp;fu=128&amp;bc=31&amp;ifi=2&amp;uci=a!2&amp;fsb=1&amp;xpc=DDOUpZiKeH&amp;p=https%3A//sharedkitchen.site&amp;dtd=3454" data-google-container-id="a!2" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>
```

I think the problem is the iframe. How can I view the page without the white space?

Answer (score 0):

There is an element there with the class "code-block". Inside that there seems to be google adsense code with a blank iframe. Try to delete that block on the wordpress page. If it is not there then probably a plugin or the theme that has inserted that there. There are 2 more iframes by google adsense one before and one after you body closing tag.